# How to use properly remove() for sets in python?

Tags: python-3.x, remove-if

My example is pretty simple, but still: a have a set called basket with n elements (we enter n and then the elements). And what I want is to remove all elements with 'apple' in them. However there can be cases where there is no 'apple' in the set at all and that's when it bugs. When there is 'apple' it's ok.

```
n = int(input("n= "))
basket = set()
print(f"{n} elements: ")
for i in range(n):
    e = input(f"element {i+1}: ")
    basket.add(e)
print(basket)
basket.remove('apple')
print(basket)
```

I expected to be ok even when there is no 'apple' in the set, but it gives error.

Comment: If you want to remove an element without caring whether or not it actually exists already, use `.discard()` instead of `.remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set.discard`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.discard) instead of [`set.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.remove).

From the docs:

> `remove(elem)`
>     Remove element elem from the set. Raises `KeyError` if `elem` is not contained in the set.
>
> `discard(elem)`
>     Remove element `elem` from the set if it is present.

`remove` raise a `KeyError` if the element is not present. `discard` does not.

Comment: @SimonaDavarska Glad it was helpful. But see also [Thanks in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267490/11082165)